# injecting a pcm s16be array into novocaine audiomanager

Tags: pcm, novocaine

To @alexbw and friends, 
First of all thanks for this great piece of code. 
I have pcm data (signed 16 bit big endian) in a byte array and I want to play it with Novocaine AudioManager setOutputBlock.
I understand I first need to convert to a float array. 
Or is there a faster way?
Cheers
Philippe

Comment: Did you find a best way to do this? Convert indeed? Or does Novocaine also take integer based audio?

Answer (score 0):

Late, but for anyone else reading:

You can use the Accelerate framework here:

`float *float_data = malloc(sizeof(float) * numFrames);
vDSP_vflt16(my_s16_data, 1, float_data, 1, numFrames);
//Scaling [-32768, 32768] to [-1, 1]
float scale = 1.0 / (float)INT16_MAX;
vDSP_vsmul(float_data, 1, &scale, float_data, 1, numFrames);`

And "float_data" will now have the float equivalent.